# How to grab the content of command "who" except 'pts/0'?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cut

I have this output of the command `who`:

```
$ who
user pts/0        2016-11-16 08:59 (10.10.10.11)
```

How can I grab the content of `who` excluding the `pts/0`value?

so it will display something like:

```
user      2016-11-16 08:59 (10.10.10.11)
```

Comment: Since the username cannot contain spaces, it is just a matter of removing the 2nd column.

Comment: Do you know the command?

Comment: See the linked question and take Ed Morton's answer.

Comment: I am learning awk....   This did it:        who | awk '{print " "$1" "$3" "$4" "$5}'

Comment: Note `" "` is default, so you can also say `awk '{print $1, $3, $4, $5}'` and spaces will occur in between fields.

Comment: thank you I even got it to insert spaces and add text....                          who | awk '{print $1,"     " $3,$4," at  " $5,"From IP " $6}'